# Find Outer Edges On A Grid

Tags: algorithm, math, grid

I am working with an algorithm that has a grid of constructed dots, each with an X and Y coordinate. The grid is split into several procedural areas. I am looking for a way to find the outer edges of each area (different areas are indicated by different colors) via the vertices present in these areas. I have a 2D array of all the vertices in the grid, as well as 2D arrays for each individual area, containing all of the vertices in that area.

[image: This image displays the algorithm]

I am now wondering how to create an algorithm that finds the outer edges of each area, while discounting the "inner" parts. I am currently using C# in Unity3d, but programming language isn't really important. I'm looking for a general algorithm of how this would hypothetically be done. I do not quite know where to start

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: @gunr2171 Thank you, I have done my best to edit my question. I am looking for a description of an algorithm that could do this, as I am not really sure where or how to start. I have also removed the C# tag as this is a more general question

Answer (score 0):

You can identify an edge-dot like this:

It is a dot that (any of):

- has a neighbor that is of different color than itself
- it is on the edge of the grid.

Algorithm:
Loop through all the dots and test each dots (up to) 4 neighbors to determine if either of the two above points applies.

Complexity:  O(n) (in the number of dots)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lightly altered version of Christian Sloper' suggestion:

For each dot, find the dots on the 4 closest dots on the diagonals (top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right). If 1 or 3 of them are a different color, the dot's coordinate is the corner of a shape.